# How to transpose a table in Power BI from Row to Column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, data-transform

I am having trouble structuring my PowerBI data in the required format. I am attaching the data structure below.

My Data Structure:

[image]

Required Output Structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Step-1:** Go to **Power Query Editor** and right click on your **ID** column and select **GROUP BY** option and select other options as below-

[image]

**Now** you will get table per **ID** as shown below-

[image]

**Step-2:** Add a custom column as below-

[image]

**Step-3:** Extract values from the list column using comma separation as shown below-

[image]

Now you have records as below-

[image]

**Step-4:** Finally split the new column using **Comma** again and you will find the output as below-

[image]

**Step-5:** Remove the column **AllRecords** and rename new columns as per your requirement.